# Reading the transactional dead-letter queue by wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, dead-letter

I'm trying to create a dead letter queue service in wcf with following service configuration:

```
<service name="NotificationDeadLetterQueueService">
 <endpoint
  address="net.msmq://localhost/system$;DeadXact"
  binding="netMsmqBinding"
  contract="INotificationService"
/>
</service>
```

If I start the service host, I get a System.Messaging.MessageQueueException saying "Invalid queue path name". What is wrong in the transactional system dead letter queue adress? I can not find any other examples in the net.

Comment: no the service does not use a configured netMsmqBinding

Comment: The exception is thrown at the queue verification and I found out, that the queue verification is only made for private queues and doe snot work with "$" in the address.